# how to get a .phar file real directory within the phar file code?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, phar

I am trying to create a php executable (a phar file) for generating some files, and I would like to know how to get the real path of the phar file (within the phar file code).

What I want to do is to create a folder in the same level of the phar file and create the new files there, but `realpath(__DIR__.'/../')` does not seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28775172/282601 the `__FILE__` constant has the full path with the scheme:

```
phar:///home/cweiske/Dev/test/phar/test.phar/path/to/foo.php
```

`__DIR__` is similar:

```
phar:///home/cweiske/Dev/test/phar/test.phar/path/to
```

So when calling `realpath(__DIR__)` you still have the `phar://` prefix that prevents you from loading the file.

You have to remove the `phar://` scheme as well as the path of the file inside the `.phar` to get the phar location with `__DIR__`.

---

Much easier is [`Phar::running(false)`](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.running.php), which simply returns the path:

```
/home/cweiske/Dev/test/phar/test.phar
```

Comment: That only gets the path of CURRENT file, not the relative or other file.

Comment: Behaviour of `Phar::running` and `__FILE__` changes within the context of the PHAR stub. In those cases, `Phar::running(true/false)` will always return `''`, and `__FILE__` will return the PHAR path _without_ `phar://` at the beginning. 

This is mentioned briefly on https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.running.php : "Inside the stub of an archive, Phar::running() returns "". Simply use \_\_FILE\_\_ to access the current running phar inside a stub. "

Answer (score 1):

**the answer is**

```
 $string = 'phar://E:/php/www/my.phar';
 $string = pathinfo($string);
 $_dir_ = parse_url($string['dirname']);
 echo $_dir_['host'].':/'.$_dir_['path'];
```

**result**

`E:/php/www`