# Get name of current file inside Phar archive

Tags: php, file, path, constants, phar

I'm currently learning about *PHP archives (Phars)* and I know that in PHP `__FILE__` always is the absolute filename of the currently executing file.

But to which file does `__FILE__` point to if the script is inside a Phar? Is it the absolute filename of the Phar itself, or the Phar-URL to the current script inside the Phar?

For example: If I have a Phar located at `/path/to/my.phar` which contains a stub script, and a PHP script located at `phar:///path/to/my.phar/inside/inner.php`. What would `__FILE__` be in the stub and `inner.php`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27838025/367456

Answer (score 1):

You could have tried it yourself.

The short answer is that `__FILE__` has the full path; it's

```
phar:///home/cweiske/Dev/test/phar/test.phar/path/to/foo.php
```

in my test case - see http://p.cweiske.de/172